# COPY from SELECT query result ? (in postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql,
I need to insert data to, say table B from sql query that get query from table A and table C.
This sample is the best that I can get:

`SELECT (SELECT bic FROM bank where name='Bank Foo'), curr_id FROM currency where 
alpha_id = 'AUD'
OR alpha_id ='NZD'
OR alpha_id ='SGD';`

The result is something like this:

```
 ?column? | curr_id
----------+---------
 xyz      |      9
 xyz      |     66
 xyz      |      4
```

My question are :

1) how to make the result more prettier, instead of ?column? the field should show 'bic'?

2) To insert data to table B, I think I just use COPY  but I have no idea how to get data from a query statement like above. Is it possible?
Any better suggestion are welcomed.

(Usually I use COPY from csv file, ok  I know you guys can say just copy paste the result to csv file and COPY but 
that means I don't learn something new :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Give the column an alias, `SELECT (SELECT bic FROM bank where name='Bank Foo') bic, curr_id ...`
2. INSERT INTO can take a query. e.g. `INSERT INTO B SELECT (SELECT bic FROM bank where name='Bank Foo'), curr_id FROM currency where alpha_id = 'AUD' OR alpha_id ='NZD' OR alpha_id ='SGD'`